# If $G$ is simple, then $\epsilon \leq {v \choose 2}$ - Bondy/Murty - Graph Theory with Applications Page 4

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> **Question:** Does this proof hold? Is this a bad proof? Any nicer proofs that don't rely on other theorems?

Notation:

- $\epsilon$ - Number of edges
- $v$ - Number of vertices
- G - Here, any Graph

> If $G$ is simple, then $\epsilon \leq {v \choose 2}$

Proof: For each simple graph we have no loops, and only one edge connecting each pair of vertices. A graph with no isolated vertices and all vertices connected to a single vertex will minimise $\frac{v}{\epsilon}$ in this case we can see:

- $\epsilon = 1 \implies v=2$
- $\epsilon = 2 \implies v=3$
- $\cdot$
- $\cdot$
- $\epsilon = n \implies v= n+1$

So $v = \epsilon +1$ in the minimal $\frac{v}{\epsilon}$ case, and hence:

$\epsilon \leq {{\epsilon + 1} \choose 2} =\frac{(\epsilon + 1)!}{(\epsilon -1)! 2!}=\frac{(\epsilon + 1)\epsilon}{2}=\frac{\epsilon^2 + \epsilon}{2}$

$$\epsilon \leq \frac{\epsilon^2 + \epsilon}{2} $$
$$2\epsilon \leq \epsilon^2 + \epsilon$$
$$\epsilon \leq \epsilon^2$$
$$1 \leq \epsilon$$

Which is true.

Therefore, $G$ being simple implies $\epsilon \leq {v \choose 2}$

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof you have given is much more complicated than need be, and if you are going to go about proving each individual step, you will actually need to display the inductive method that was assumed for the (intuitively obvious) $v=\epsilon +1$ minimization.  Furthermore, $\frac{v}{\epsilon}$ is not a particularly rigorous concept, being that it is essentially meaningless beyond potentially human understanding.

What would work much better would be a proof by contradiction:

Assume that there is some $G$ that is both simple and has $\epsilon\gt {v\choose 2}$

If $\epsilon \gt {v \choose 2}=\frac{v!}{(v-2)!2!}=\frac{v(v-1)}{2}=\frac{v^2-v}{2}$

$$2\epsilon \gt v^2-v$$

Each edge requires at least two vertices.

$2\epsilon \gt v^2 - v$

Therfore for $\epsilon \geq 3$ the above isn't true. Therefore we have a contradiction, hence $\epsilon \leq {V \choose 2}$

Answer (score 2):

I don't really follow your argument, but it seems like you're making this much more complicated than it is.  If a graph is simple, then an edge is determined by a pair of vertices.  Since there are only $\binom{v}{2}$ pairs of vertices, there can be no more than $\binom{v}{2}$ edges.

Comment: Off-topic question: Why is this a community wiki?

On-topic question: Your proof makes sense intuitively and was essentially what I was trying to write mathematically, but I failed clearly. I will try again and edit this post accordingly. Thank you for your input thus far.

Comment: Oh I see, I can do a proof by contradiction, by assuming that we can have more edges than pairs of vertices. Thank you!(I am still interested in the answer to the off-topic question)